# Anaconda NumPy (SciPy stack) performance on Ryzen 3000 and windows

Tags: windows, numpy, amd-processor, openblas

I have a new Ryzen CPU and ran into [this issue](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/AMD-Ryzen-3900X-vs-Intel-Xeon-2175W-Python-numpy---MKL-vs-OpenBLAS-1560/). Eg. default anaconda channel uses Intel MKL and this cripples performance on Ryzen systems. If a numpy version using openblas is used, then it's much faster. The above example is in ubuntu but I need to achieve this in windows as well.

To be more specific I actually managed to install numpy with openblas but as soon I try to install anything on top like scikit-learn it will "downgrade" to mkl again.

What I'm looking for is install instructions for a "SciPy stack" python environment on windows using openblas?

EDIT:

This issue seems to be extremely annoying. While there is since not very long a nomkl package also for windows it doesn't seem to take as it always installs mkl version regardless. Even if I install from pip, conda will just overwrite it, with an mkl version again next time you install something, in my case another lib which requires conda.

EDIT2:

As far as I can tell for now the only "solution" is to install anything SciPy related from pypi (pip): numpy, SciPy, pandas, scikit-learn possibly more. eg. only really a solution if you really need anaconda for a specific package, which I do.

EDIT3:

So the `MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5` trick indeed works. Performance with mkl is restored and a bit better than with openblas.
I did a very basic test (see the link above) with a fixed seed and the result is the same for mkl and openblas.

Comment: I did find that but seem unmaintained and hence not sure it has an upgrade path.

Comment: This is a easy workaround for all MKL related problems (Matlab Numpy Scipy and many more) https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/dxn38s/howto_force_matlab_to_use_a_fast_codepath_on_amd/

Comment: @max9111 thanks! I will try this out on my ryzen system once I get the chance. This would help a lot. The only other option is to either use conda-forge (but scipy still needs to come from pip) or not use conda at all or switch to Linux.

Comment: Does anyone know if this problem shows up with R and Ryzen CPUs?

Comment: @ErikRuzek If you use a R Version with MKL (Intel Math Kernel Library) yes.

Comment: What about if you use the generic base R version from CRAN? Does that use MKL? My impression is no, but it also seems like you can get even better performance on Ryzen by using OpenBLAS (e.g., https://github.com/cvanpay/R_OpenBLAS_Zen)